# How to add hair in OpenGL

Tags: opengl

I have a 3D head model. How can I add hair? I only need to draw hair and animation is not required.

Could anyone provide some sample code? What is the simplest way to simulate hair in this case?

**Edit:**

I understand this is not a programming problem. But I have to implement it as my project. I searched online, which makes me more confusing. That is why I asked here.

Comment: Do you want to just draw hair (which requires only a texture with alpha channel) or simulate it (which requires strand physics and some shaders)?

Comment: I don't really see a programming question here. Hair is more of a design issue, especially if animation or simulation or not needed.

Comment: ..ARE not needed. (I should learn to type)

Comment: Even a cursory web search should have revealed that this is an area of research unto itself.  This question is too vague.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Static hair can be rendered in a variety of ways depending on your needs:

- Using a polygonal model. This gives hair that looks like what the characters from Dragon Ball or Yugi Oh! have.
- Using a fur rendering algorithm. This is a very fill-rate intensive process.
- Using multiple disjointed polygonal models. This works well for dreaded hair and in general hair which isn't too "fluffy".

These are just from the top of my head. There are most likely other algorithms out there. Also, as cbamber85, hair rendering is indeed a research field in itself!